# Angular5 How to prevent page reload when url changes

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

Let's say that I have a MainPage component (localhost:4200/mainPage) that has a button. I click on that button and Upload component renders on the same page. But when Upload component is visible, I need URL to be different (localhost:4200/mainPage/upload). But I don't want the page refresh when URL changes. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please try to back up your question with code so that everyone can understand the context and the problem. Are you trying to do something different from conventional Angular routing? (which in itself updates the components without page load). Le me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
 <button class="btn btn-warning" routerLink="/mainPage/upload" skipLocationChange> Create New </button>
```

In this case you will be routed to the page upload..no refresh will occur